# What is the best way to connect two Macs to minimize network latency?

Tags: mac, networking, ethernet, latency

What is the best way to connect two Mac Minis, one running Lion and the other one running Snow Leopard, to **minimize latency** for sharing screen?

Right now they are connected through a wireless network (using the same wireless network), and I am thinking of also connecting them both using Ethernet.

I guess I can connect both of them using Gigabit Ethernet to form another private network between the two. What other options do I have?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has and hasn't worked? This really shows no effort on your part

Comment: they are now connected through wireless network, and other than some latency it's ok. i haven't tried connecting them through ethernet yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides gigabit Ethernet, you can also use FireWire, **provided that neither computer has other FireWire devices connected.**  Connect the two hosts with a FireWire cable and both hosts will notice the link and choose link-local IP addresses in the 169.254/16 range.  The remote host will show up under Network in Finder and you can access its screen as usual.

Comment: thanks, i wonder which one is faster, gigabit ethernet or firewire..in theory, gigabit ethernet is faster..

Comment: Unless you have optical cables, FireWire maximum length is less than 5m. This limits the need for screen sharing.